# How to remove borders for ListTile leading icon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use `ListTile` with borders. But I want to hide borders above and below leading icon. To do something like this.

[image]

For example, look at `Privacy` item. It doesn't have borders around leading icon.

This is my code:

```
ListTile(
  shape: Border(
    bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey),
    top: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey),
  ),
  leading: Icon(Icons.person, size: 32),
  title: const Text("Contact", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
)
```

But it adds borders also above and below icon. Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: If you use more than one ListTile, you can give Divider() to the sepratorBuilder: property of ListView.separated().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This UI is grouping item. There are others way of doing it. Here are three items(`itemCount:3`) and It is inside `ListView.separated`. Every Item(group) have border Radius.

A single item can be Wrapped with Column to contain children and again wrapped with another widget

```dart
ListView.separated(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [...],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    separatorBuilder: (_, __) => SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
    itemCount: 3),
```